# How to stop systemd-resolved switching DNS servers

Tags: dns

I have a local DNS resolver configuration and I am not sure why my DNS resolvers are switching. Here is my configuration

**#cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf**

```
[Resolve]
DNS=W.X.Y.Z
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=example.com
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=no-negative
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

**#cat /etc/resolve.conf**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
 search example.com test.xxnet.com
```

But when I see **#systemd-resolve --status**

```
Current DNS Server: A.B.C.D
     DNS Servers: W.X.Y.Z
                  A.B.C.D
      DNS Domain: example.com
                  test.xxnet.com
```

I have 3 questions here:

1. why DNS servers are switching even though I used timeout 5 in /etc/resolv.conf?
2. where does A.B.C.D come from?
3. how to stop switching or only use W.X.Y.Z as a DNS resolver?

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

From `man systemd-resolved`, emphasis mine:

> The DNS servers contacted are determined from
>
> the global settings in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`,
>
> the per-link static settings in `/etc/systemd/network/*.network` files (in case `systemd-networkd.service(8)` is used),
>
> **the per-link dynamic settings received over DHCP**,
>
> information provided via `resolvectl(1)`,
>
> **and** any DNS server information made available by other system services.

The resulting list of DNS servers to use is a combination of **all** these sources. So probably your DHCP server specifies A.B.C.D as the DNS server to use, and `test.xxnet.com` as the domain to use. That makes A.B.C.D as a *connection-specific DNS server*, which also makes it the preferred DNS server for that connection.

That also means `*.example.com` names would be queried from both A.B.C.D and W.X.Y.Z, but `*.test.xxnet.com` names would be queried from A.B.C.D only, since the search domain `test.xxnet.com` was (probably) also supplied from the connection-specific DNS configuration (received by DHCP).

You might have to tell your DHCP client to ignore the DNS configuration supplied by the DHCP server.

How to do that depends on two things:

- which DHCP client are you using? (`dhclient` and `dhcpcd` are common)
- are you configuring the DHCP client directly, or is it configured by `NetworkManager` or some other network configuration management system?

Please *edit your question* to supply this information, and I'll update this answer accordingly if I can.